# Jenkins Project Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm having a problem with **compiling** a simple **maven project** in **Jenkins**, I don't understand what happened.

This project compiles perfectly out for Jenkins server.
I am using  JDK 8, Maven 3.3.9, operation system **Ubuntu Server**.

### Error Log:

```
Established TCP socket on 37158<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started Executing Maven:  -N -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AArcoOneProject/AArco-One-Pojo/pom.xml compile
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:133)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:68)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Lanzada por el usuario Diego Fernando Hidalgo Cornejo
Finished: ABORTED
FATAL: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:173)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:68)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to Channel to Maven [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java, -cp, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main, /opt/apache-maven-3.3.3, /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.62.3.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar, 37158](Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1433)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:797)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:161)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$MavenBuildExecution.doRun(MavenBuild.java:880)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild.run(MavenBuild.java:270)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:133)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:68)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:189)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    ... 14 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: does the complete log read the reactor order from maven or is this the first thing that you see after building?

Comment: This is complete log of jenkins, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check which `settings.xml` file is in used, run `mvn` with `-X` , you will see in the start of the output which file is used.

I had the same issue, when mvn used the default file and we used another file on our local env.

BTW, did you install MVN on the slave or Jenkins did it for you?

Comment: Just download maven unpack it create the environment variables, out of jenkins the project compiles well,